# Is there some application to edit local wiki pages in WYSIWYG mode ON windows?

Tags: wiki, wysiwyg

I am searching for some application which will help me with writing project documentation.
From what i understand now, gollum and gitit should help me with that, but it seems that they can't be used on windows.

**Features wanted:**

1. I want to edit files directly `"messaging.textile", "notificationSystem.textile"` for example (any format is good), so files should be saved as ordinary text
2. Cross platform (win,linux and mac)